# How many non-isomorphic, simple, connected graphs with 6 vertices are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, integer-sequences

A graph is called simple if there are no loops and there are no multiple edges. Is it possible to compute the number of non-isomorphic, simple, connected graphs with 6 vertices? If the number is known, how we obtain this number? Thank you in advance!

Comment: C'mon, this is not for MO. Just use invariants, one after another: first, the number of edges, then the number of components, the ramification, etc. Children will have fun.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is $112$.

This is available at OEIS:

[Number of connected graphs with n nodes](https://oeis.org/A001349)

You can enumerate small graphs with Nauty:
https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-geng

Or try the following sagemath code, possibly in a browser:

```
cou=0                                                                     
for g0 in graphs(6): 
  if g0.is_connected():  cou += 1
```